# Python - Spyder isn't displaying the entire Pandas DataFrame (whereas VSC is displaying it correctly)

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

I've been trying to make a minesweeper board on Spyder, but I've encountered a problem with my pandas data frame. The values in the grid are colored (using colorama).

the program:

```
import numpy 
import pandas
from colorama import Fore

def color(col, mot):
    if col=="red":
        mot =  Fore.RED + str(mot) + Fore.RESET
    if col=="white":
        mot =  Fore.WHITE + str(mot) + Fore.RESET
    if col =="blue":
        mot = Fore.BLUE + str(mot) + Fore.RESET
    if col == "green":
        mot = Fore.GREEN + str(mot) + Fore.RESET
    return mot

grid = [['\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m'], ['\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m'], ['\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m'], ['\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m'], ['\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m'], ['\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m'], ['\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m'], ['\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m'], ['\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m'], ['\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m', '\x1b[37m.\x1b[39m']]

x = numpy.array(grid)
row_labels = ['L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4','L5','L6','L7','L8','L9','L10']
column_labels = [color("white",'C1'), color("white",'C2'), color("white",'C3'), color("white",'C4'),color("white",'C5'),color("white",'C6'),color("white",'C7'),color("white",'C8'),color("white",'C9'),color("white",'C10')]

df = pandas.DataFrame(x,columns=column_labels, index=row_labels)

print("-------------" + color("red", "Demineur") + "-------------")
print()
print(df)
print()
print("----------------------------------")
```

Using visual studio code :
[the dataframe on VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHS38.png)

Using spyder :
[the same dataframe on spyder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPACj.png)

I've already tried to use :

```
pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None)
```

but didn't work

How can I get the same result that I get on VSC, on Spyder ?

Let me know if you want more information.

Thanks, Ikseno

Comment: I would use some big values instead of `None`

Comment: you can try `print( df.to_string() )`

Comment: Thank you for your ideas, I think the problem came from the : None like you said. Goodbye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these settings right after your pandas.DataFrame call:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(x,columns=column_labels, index=row_labels)
pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pandas.set_option('display.width', 1000)
```

I get this in Spyder with those settings:

[image]